# Backup Hyper-V VMs during replication

Tags: windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

I currently use Hyper-V and am replicating all VMs to a second data centre. This satisfies my requirements in terms of a server failure.

What it doesn't cover is creating VM backups because if, for example, a VM were to become compromised or corrupt, this corruption would also be replicated.

I'd like to use a tool such as Veeam or similar, but how would this work if the VM is in the process of being replicated? Surely the backup would not be valid.

My goal would be to have at least 7 days backups of each VM that I could revert back to in the above case of data corruption.

I currently have 15 minute replication which is more than enough for my requirements, but it's still not enough time to take a copy of the VM before the next replica starts.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: The backup would be backing up the source VM and would be perfectly valid. Why not kill two birds with one stone with this? - https://www.veeam.com/vm-backup-recovery-replication-software.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'd maybe like to explore alternatives, Veeam is looking quite expensive for my setup and I already have replication in place using Hyper-V replication. I guess I was hoping there would be an easier, more cost effective way of copying the replicated VM's off the replica server. I could maybe write a script to pause replication, copy the VM's and re-enable replication, but that seems a bit too complicated. Thanks.